# Display the full Joomla article in Articles-category module

Tags: joomla3.0, article

I have an Articles-category module assigned at home page. It only show a list of article titles and intro-text. Now I want to show full article (with all imagines and text) for each item list.

Please help.

Comment: If you need full articles, then the best option is go for the menu item blog layout, the module is not for this purpose, Also you can find more extensions to display content here: https://extensions.joomla.org/category/news-display/articles-display/

Comment: Hi AlejandroVega, I found a solution for this problem by using module. First, edit help.php of Articles-category module, delete the codes functioned to trip introtext style. Second, edit default.php, replace the code    <?php // introtext ?>
     <p class="mod-articles-category-introtext">
      <?php echo $item->displayIntrotext; ?>
     </p>
    <?php endif; ?>        by   <p class="mod-articles-category-introtext">
  <?php echo $item->introtext; ?>
</p>